# How to access client side variables in server side code using Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm struggling with something here a bit. I've got some client-side code that requests to user to enter some data into a form.

I want to use this data (just two integer variables) on the server side.

How do I define these variables and access them?

Comment: you can pass variables while requesting server. No ?

Comment: Have you written any code attempting to do what you are asking? If so, please post it within your question.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call a server side code from the client side, and pass the values, when you call the serverside code. 
Example:

```
function someClientSide(){
  //do smt here
  let v1 = foo
  let v2 = bar
  Meteor.call("updateTwoVariables", v1, v2)
}
```

Some resource for api methods: 
https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks! I've sort of figured it out using collections, but i think it's a bit of a work around. Does your method though all your to access v1 and v2 on the serverside using Meteor.call ?

Comment: Yes. If you use like this, you will get the the result in the terminal
`Meteor.methods({
  updateTwoVariables(v1, v2){
    console.log(v1, v2)
  }
})`